# How to publish APK to Google Play Store?

Tags: android, apk, publish

I have developed my first Android app. I want to publish on Google Play Store.

Before that I'm in doubt if I either want to publish a different APK for mobile and tab or a single APK for both the supported screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to create separate APK file.

Single Apk file development enough to support Phone and tab.

You have to do responsive view in your XML file using dimen.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same apk for phones and tablets.

The only things that changes are the screenshots for the diferents screen sizes.

You can see the instructions to publish on google play [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/start.html)

Comment: if my post helps you please approve and vote my answer.

Comment: if my post helps you please approve my answer. It's important for me. Tks

Answer (score 0):

You must make the app for compatible in all devices with xml code.

And publish apk with [this tutorial](http://support.andromo.com/kb/distributing/how-to-put-your-app-in-google-play).